# Search returns no result in Live Object's Kibana

Tags: orange-api

I have an account on the tenant ZZZ OBE smart tracking. Kibana seems available, but when I click on it I don't see any data. Search returns empty results.
How can I configure Kibana properly for this account ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the answer is in the FAQ : My new data are not visible in Kibana